# Maximum Segment Sum with negative numbers

Tags: algorithm, dynamic, numbers, intervals

Given N numbers (positive and negative) and T = number of numbers you can choose, how can you compute the maximum sum of intervals? The first number from an interval is considered to be 0.

For example:
N=5 T=4 and {3 9 1 1 7}
the maximum sum is 16 from (3, 9) and (1, 7) ! Remember 3 and 1 are considered to be 0 because they are the first numbers in their intervals.
I came up with a solution for this, but when i add negative numbers it messes up.
N=4 T=3 and {-2 1 -3 -4}
solution is 1 (-2, 1) and (-3 -3) (when you work with negative numbers, you can consider an interval formed by the same negative number (-3 -3) = 0).
Any ideas?

*LATER EDIT: what is wrong with my code? http://pastebin.com/QTTTrvUz

Comment: N=5 T=4 and {3 9 1 1 7} the maximum sum is 16 from (3, 9) and (1, 7) - if T=4, you can choose 4 out of the 5 numbers? no?

Comment: Yes, T is the number of numbers you can choose.

Comment: I've tried this:

for(int i=1; i<T; i++){
   max_j=0;int iul=0;
   if(i==T-i)
    iul = local_maximum(0, i)+maxim_local(max_j, T-i);
   else
    iul = local_maximum(0, i)+maxim_local(0, T-i);
   
   if(iul>max_seq)
    max_seq=iul;
     
  }

Comment: By the way, this is **not** the Maximum Segment Sum problem, since you can choose more than one segment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Planning activities in order to get maximum profit using dynamic programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15533538/planning-activities-in-order-to-get-maximum-profit-using-dynamic-programming)

Answer (score 1):

[Dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) is your friend:

Let `S[i][j]` denote the maximum sum that can be obtained while considering only the first `i` numbers, given that we can choose `j` numbers.

Then either:

1. `S[i][j] = S[i - 1][j]`, if `i` is not in a segment.
2. `S[i][j] = S[i - k][j - k] + value_of_segment(i - k + 1, i)`, if `i` is in a segment of length `k`.

We let `S[i][j] = max((1), (2))`.

`value_of_segment` can be pre-computed in `O(n)`.

`S[i][j]` can be computed in `O(N * T^2)`.

Comment: I try the following code:
`public static int s(int val, int nr){
  
  if(val==0) return 0;
  
  
     if(k<val)
   {
      k++;
      aux1 =  s(val-1, nr);
   }
  
  if(k==val){
   aux2 = s(val-k, nr-k) + sum(val-k, val);
   k=1;
   
  }
  
  return(max(aux1, aux2)); 
   
  }`

k is global, k = 0 and I'm calling s(N, T).

What is wrong with it?

Comment: can you please tell me what is wrong with my code? it doesn't return the correct results. Thank you in advance.